# jQuery Conditional Form Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I've been looking around StackOverflow and a few other sites for assistance on conditional validation of form fields. Most of the questions are related to checkboxes, however mine issue is around a select field.

I have deployed jQuery and jQueryUI and all is working correctly on that front. I haven't installed jQuery Validate as I think this can be achieved without it, but would be happy to be told otherwise. Here is the problem:

If the user selects "open", then the "dateOpened" field needs to be required. If they select "closed" then the "dateClosed" will be required.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="select12" id="select12">
  <option>Select...</option>
  <option value="1">Open</option>
  <option value="2">Closed</option>
</select>

<input name="dateOpened" id="dateOpened" type="text" />
<input name="dateClosed" id="dateClosed" type="text" />

<input name="submit" type="submit"  value="update"/>
</form>
```

Can anyone advise the best solution?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: where is your validation script? or do you want to have required attribute for input fields?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8T3Tj/2/  i don't want to post it as answer since you already use JQuery validate, and i am not sure about your current validation process... but, this is some basic logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, hope it helps -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#update" ).click(function() {
    var abc = $( "#select12" ).val();
    if ( abc == "1" ) {
        var open = $("#dateOpened").val();
        alert(open);
        }
    else { 
        var close = $("#dateClosed").val();
        alert(close);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select name="select12" id="select12">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Open</option>
    <option value="2">Closed</option>
</select>
<input name="dateOpened" id="dateOpened" type="text" />
<input name="dateClosed" id="dateClosed" type="text" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="update"  value="update"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect - just had to add && $("#dateOpened").val()=='' to the first and replicate with different ID to the second of the if statement and it's working perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#select12').on('change',function() {
  if($(this).val()=="1") {
    $('#dateOpened').prop('required',true);
    $('#dateClosed').removeAttr('required');
  }
  if($(this).val()=="2") {
    $('#dateClosed').prop('required',true);
    $('#dateOpened').removeAttr('required');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "validate" plugin and write my own validation method - something like this:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("dateValMethod", function (value, element) {
    var valid = false;
    if ((value== 1 && value_of_dateOpened_not_empty) || (value== 2 && value_of_dateClosed_not_empty)) {
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
 }, "Please blah blah blah...");
```